# How many apps are the Mac AppStore?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Is there a way to find out today how many applications are in the Mac AppStore approximately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [AppShopper.com](http://appshopper.com) to get information like this.  In the right sidebar of every page, it shows the total stats of all the app stores.  For example, as of 18 Sep 2011 at 5:10pm GMT, the sidebar shows:

> **Total Apps**
>
> Total Apps Approved: 595452
>
> Total Available Apps: 462144
>
> Total Available iPhone Apps: 411134
>
> Total Available iPad Apps: 132388
>
> Total Available Mac Apps: 6939

Comment: @NathanGreenstein better? :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a Browse button when you're in the App Store in iTunes. As long as you don't do it from within an App Store Category it should give you a complete list of apps. At the top you should see something that tells you that you're in page 1 of X where X is the total number of pages. Multiply that by the number of apps in each page and you have your number. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah good point. Except I can't find a "all categories". By the way I'm talking about the Mac app store, not iOS (therefore not iTunes)

Comment: My bad. I misread your question. And yes, the Mac App Store does not have a similar page. Having said that, the best way to get the exact number on any given day should be thru Apple. Maybe on the web version of the Mac App Store? You know, when you search for an app online and the app makers links to it; if you don't have the Mac App Store installed (like, if you're on a PC) then your browser will open on a web-front for the store. I wonder if there are browsing features from there.

Comment: This link takes you to a browser version of the Mac App Store. It is  easier to browse here than on the actual Mac App Store on your Mac: http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mac/id39?mt=12